# Antiderivative problem

Tags: integration

What is the antiderivative of $(2x+7)^{1/2}$?

My understanding is that it would be $\frac 23 \times(2x+7)^{3/2}$ but according to the source I am working from the answer is $\frac 13 \times (2x+7)^{3/2}$.

Comment: Differentiate your answer and you will see why. HINT: Chain rule.

Comment: You probably forgot to process the coefficient of $x$.

Comment: Why do I need to process the coefficient of x before I take the antiderivative?

Comment: Because it is going to be processed when you take the derivative.  If it changes in one direction, it has to change in both directions, or else the derivative of an antiderivative wouldn't equal the original function.

Answer (score 7):

$$\int\sqrt{(2x+7)}dx$$

Set $t=2x+7$ and $dt=2dx$

$$=\frac 1 2\int\sqrt tdt=\frac{t^{3/2}}{3}+\mathcal C=\frac{(2x+7)^{3/2}}{3}+\mathcal C$$

Comment: Why multiply it by 1/2 and also by 2?

Comment: @user252704 its because $dt=2dx$...therefore $dx=\dfrac{dt}{2}$...now all we need to do is to plug in the values...

Answer (score 5):

Notice:

$$\int x^n\space\text{d}x=\frac{x^{1+n}}{1+n}+\text{C}$$

---

---

$$\int\sqrt{2x+7}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=2x+7$ and $\text{d}u=2\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$\frac{1}{2}\int\sqrt{u}\space\text{d}u=\frac{1}{2}\int u^{\frac{1}{2}}\space\text{d}u=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{u^{1+\frac{1}{2}}}{1+\frac{1}{2}}+\text{C}=\frac{u^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}+\text{C}=\frac{(2x+7)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}+\text{C}$$

Comment: Why multiply it by 1/2 and also by 2?

Comment: To make the substitution clear

Answer (score 3):

$$(2x+7)^{1/2}=2^{1/2}(x+\frac72)^{1/2}\to2^{1/2}\frac1{\frac32}(x+\frac72)^{3/2}=\frac{2^{3/2}}3(x+\frac72)^{3/2}=\frac{(2x+7)^{3/2}}3.$$

Comment: Why do I need to process the coefficient of x before I take the antiderivative?

Comment: I noticed that you didn't handle it properly so this is a workaround.

Comment: @user252704, it's like the chain rule in reverse... (2x+7)^(1/2) is like f(g), where f(x) = x^(1/2) and g(x) = 2x+7, except here you have to remember to process the ANTIderivative of g instead of the derivative